# Как получить иконку пользователя аккаунта google при авторизации? (DJANGO)

Tags: python, django

Я использую библиотеку social-auth-app-django для авторизации через соцсети. Мне нужно что бы в аккаунте показывалась аватарка пользователя такая же как и в его google аккаунте. Например в stackoverflow сверху показывается моя иконка аккаунта google.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439028/how-to-get-gmail-social-avatar-using-social-auth-app-django

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575713/retrieving-profile-picture-from-google-and-facebook-in-python-social-auth я использовал этот вариант, не много изменил чтобы работало, но я не понимаю что означает user.save() и куда он это сохраняет.